# Using local storage on Android webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, local-storage

I am experimenting with Android code:  I would like to store one value using HTML 5 local storage.   For this exercise I' using a page as simple as this one:
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local_clickcount

My manifest does allow me to hit the internet, and it is min-sdk of 7.

Here is my java code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabasePath("");
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.xyz.com/test.html");
    ///xyz.com/test.html is a sample  :)
    webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
}
```

My problem is that when I close the app, the locally stored value is no longer there.  I can browse to the same page using the default browser, and the value is persistent even after closing the emulator, which is exactly the behavior  that I am looking for.

This is probably a something extremely simple....any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

It appears the empty string DatabasePath is the problem.  I tried similar code and with an empty string path, the value does not persist after the app exits.  If I define a specific database path, the value persists as expected.

Try:

```
webSettings.setDatabasePath("/data/data/"+this.getPackageName()+"/databases/");
```

Comment: @MrM, sir, if your problem is solved, you should mark it as the correct answer and upvote it, you see the tick to the left side of the answer?

Comment: You should replace `"/data/data"` with "context.getFilesDir().getPath()"

Answer (score 2):

If your app use multiple webview you will still have troubles : localStorage is not correctly shared accross all webviews.

If you want to share the same data in multiple webviews the only way is to repair it with a java database and a javascript interface.

[This page](https://github.com/didimoo/AndroidLocalStorage) on github shows how to do this.

hope this help!

Comment: I also would like to mention that there is an hybrid framework, Cobalt (http://cobaltians.org) that could help you manage multiple webviews in your native apps. it is a tool for both native and web developpers. you should check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't get it working on all devices (especially with ICS) - even with database path, enabling DOMStorage etc. - using cookies instead helped me out.