# How to set value in localStorage of webView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am connecting to url which loads only if token value is set properly to my webView browser.

This is a script where null value of userToken is found when I start my webView:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
        token: localStorage.userToken
    }
});

sendToApp = function(_key, _val) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", _key + ":##sendToApp##" + _val);
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);iframe = null;
}

IsMobile = true;

$.when(

    loadData.setup()

).then(function(data) {

    Setup = data;

    Struct = new App.Collection.Struct();
    View = new App.View.Phone();
    Zone = new App.Collection.Zone();

    Zone.setAll();
    Zone.findWhere({id:"0"}).set('path', 'Favourites')
    Struct.startLoop();
});
```

I receive error:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userToken' of null" , source: http://217.76.112.72:60180/js/mobile.js (3)
```

How can I set userToken to local storage of my android webView so this value won't be null anymore?

I read few threads about webView database or javascript parameters setting but I can't find answer to my question:

JS property setting:

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of > null" in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938209/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-value-of-null-in-android)

Database topic:

[Android webview & localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899087/android-webview-localstorage)

[Using local storage on Android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556111/using-local-storage-on-android-webview)

For example in those topics people are setting path to some kind of database which from what I understood is localStorage but if am I right how can I set value to it?

Edit: my webView setup:

```
public void setupWebView(String url, String token) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("userToken", token);

    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url, map);
}
```

Comment: How is your WebView set up? This [answer might be appropriate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5934650/503508).

Comment: Hello, I have posted my webView setup. As you can see I am using .setDomStorageEnabled(true); but I don't know to which object/how should I insert my key/value so it can be read by script presented above.

Answer (score 0):

Using the 2 parameter loadUrl won't help. You won't be able to access the headers.

What you CAN do, is you can call a function in your WebView.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:setUserToken(token)");
```

You can use this function to launch the rest of your code on the page too.

```
function setUserToken(userToken) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        data: {
            token: userToken
        }
    });

    // ... Launch your ajax
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it needs to be given a moment to load the WebView the first time. You could test it, delay the execution of the send loadUrl function by a few seconds. For example, by setting it on a button to press.

Comment: sorry :D I've noticed that I need to add function to java with parameter but I don't have it

Comment: Hello I've tried: webView.loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.setItem(\"userToken\",\"" + token + "\")");

But received: "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document."